# AWS organization - I want all org users to be able to see and share all resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

My AWS IAM use case is quite basic:

We are building a quick MVP of an app and so we are quickly spinning up services that are part of it. Right now it's just 2 of us so it's not like we have a huge org to manage. We need to be able to work together quickly and all I want is a situation that results in the following:

- I created the master account. I created an organization and *invited* my friend to the org via his email (his email, and mine, and the root account email, all use the same domain, not that it matters here)
- I log into my account - my ORG account
- He logs into his account - his ORG account
- He creates functions in lambda.
- I go to the lambda dashboard and I can see and manage the functions he created
- I create something in Elastic Beanstalk
- He goes to the EB dashboard and sees and can manage the resources I created

This doesn't seem like it should be so difficult but about the nearest I can tell is that someone somewhere has to create an IAM role between the two and it has to be given switch role permissions.

Or something.

This tutorial is impossible to follow because it starts using "account" interchangeably and I don't know which it is referring to.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html#orgs_manage_accounts_create-cross-account-role

I've also tried:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

And that doesn't seem to be what I want. If I want to switch roles I'll just give my friend the username & password to the admin role, which defeats the whole point. It seems more correct that there's a role we *share* that allows us to see the resources that the other creates.

Someone who can shed some light on what should be an insanely simple thing, I'd much appreciate it...

I am 100% willing to accept my assumptions are bad. I've never done this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of what you are looking for isn't possible within the AWS console. You can grant permissions across accounts, and you can use APIs to get data across accounts, but the console is only ever going to show you data from one account. Even to use the various "list" type APIs you have to be in the context of a single account. You may be able to access a resource in another account, but you cannot see those resources together.

Bottom line, I don't think you are using organizations in the way it is expected to be used. If you just want multiple developers to have access to the same information you should just have more than one user in a single account, or, better yet, have users from an SSO log into the account via an assumed role. If you use AWS Control Tower to create your accounts it will create an SSO for you and you can add users to the SSO, and grant them access to the various accounts, with varying permissions.

Comment: That seems to be what I'm looking for, thanks! However I'm going to go with your first suggestion, we just created two IAM users, seems to do what we want. Good enough. Thanks!!